# Windows Forms equivalent of WPFs OnStartup event

Tags: c#, wpf

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
```

I want the equivalent of this event for Windows Forms.

I'm making a image viewing application. My application is one of the default programs that opens a .JPG. So how can i get the path of the file

Comment: Form.Load should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the path of the file started the process you can go about this

```
var path = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
```

To get the path of file association clicked you need to look at the command line args

```
var pathOfFileAssociation = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1] ;
```

Comment: I'm making a image viewing application. My application is one of the default programs that opens a .JPG. So how can i get the path of the file.

Comment: I think image path will be passed as commandline argument. check `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

Comment: @SriamSakthivel I tried GetCommandLineArgs but it didn't work. it just gave me the path of the executable.

Comment: Is it? I hope file path will be in second position of array. Did you tried same `GetCommandLineArgs()[1]`?

Comment: @SriamSakhivel GetCommandLineArgs()[1] this worked for me. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

In the file `Program.cs`, there should be following method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

`args` contains the parameters passed to your application, e.g. the file that should be opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //this gives you the path of the executing assembly
    MessageBox.Show(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath));
}
```

Comment: @DonBiotnott May be better to use Debug.WriteLine() instead.